# Passing json variable to a javascript function when using Jade templating engine

Tags: json, node.js, pug

Basically, I have a table that I'm creating with the Jade templating engine and node.js and in the rows of the site, I have for each row, the edit/delete option. Code is as follows,

```
       tr
            td= user.email
            td=
                a.icon-1.info-tooltip(onclick="editContact({=user._id})", title="Edit")
                a.icon-2.info-tooltip(onclick="deleteContact(=user._id)", title="Delete")
```

My problem is that the part deleteContact(=user._id) is printing as is on html, instead of showing the id. I'm new to node.js and jade, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using inline jade you need to use `#{}` to print the variable.

```
 tr
      td= user.email
      td=
          a.icon-1.info-tooltip(onclick="editContact(#{user._id})", title="Edit")
          a.icon-2.info-tooltip(onclick="deleteContact(#{user._id})", title="Delete")
```

[Documentation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/)

Comment: thanks! been stuck on this for about an hour. Jade is so confusing.